# Book that can interpret molecular properties of organic coumpounds?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-chemistry, reference-request, soft-question

I'm new in the field of research and modelling matter.

I got results from DFT calculations but I don't know how to interpret them and I wonder if anyone can suggest to me books for interpreting results (molecular properties).

Comment: +1. But what DFT calculations do you want to interpret? What did you calculate using DFT? What are the results? Can you show us results that you want help interpreting?

Comment: TDDTFT calculus transition states, UV vis Spectra..Etc